# Android SMS Sending Intent filter

Tags: android

I 'm using  in an Activity in Android so that It could receive the intent when I try to send SMS. While sending the SMS I want to get a pop up asking me which app I want to use, native sms app or my app.

My problem is that it works when I 'm resending those sms which are failed to sent in last attempt i got the pop asking to choose sms app but If i just type a message after inputting target phone no It just uses native sms app not ask choices for SMS apps

MOreover Is there any way thourgh which I could put listener to outgoing sms so that I could invoke my application.

- Regards
  Anil

Comment: Hey I'm curious how you managed to get listed as alternative sms application. And if you have found a solution to your original question as I am faced with the same problem currently. Cheers

Comment: Hi .. You have to use intent filter for particular activity in Android manifest.xml for this feature. This intent filter would be same as that in default SMS application. On declaring intent filter in your appilication and installing it on android device or emulator. the android system automatically asks for which sms application would be used. More genrically same thing can also be done for other applications to and functionalites like maps and calling.. Cheers!